# Can a negative power series have zeros in the unit dics?

Tags: complex-analysis

As title say, suppose we have the expression $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n}z^{-n}$ as an antianalytic function in $\mathbb{D}$.

Can it have zeros there? My first tought is now since these would be poles of the analytic function $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n}z^{n}$

Comment: I do not understand clearly your question. Try $2-1/z$

Comment: You seem to think of $$\left(\sum_{n=0}^∞a_nz^{-n}\right)^{-1}$$ to exchange roots for poles.

Comment: This series, in its domain of convergence (which will be the exterior of a disk, possibly along with part of the boundary), is simply an ordinary analytic function; there is no notion of "antianalytic" in this regard. There is a notion of "antianalytic" but it has nothing to do with this post; an [antianalytic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiholomorphic_function) is  a function $f$ such that $f(\bar{z})$ is analytic in $z$.

Comment: More generally, $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} a_n z^n$, if convergent, will converge on the interior of an annulus centered at the origin (possibly along with parts of its boundary), and be analytic there.

Comment: An analytic function in $\mathbb D$ does not have such an expansion, unless $a_n = 0$ for $n>0.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the same as asking if
$$
\sum_n a_nw^n
$$
can have roots outside the unit disk. There are numerous standard power series, for instance the sine series, which show that indeed that is possible.